# Need a graphing solution for a web application

Tags: web-applications, graph, data-visualization

I'm looking for a utility I can use with a web application I'm developing in TurboGears 2.1 that will allow me to generate graphs. The data we're tracking pertains to files being downloaded from distribution mirrors, and contains the filename, country of the downloader, time of the download, and which mirror. Ideally I would like a graphing framework of some sort which will allow graphing any two metrics against each other with filters applied. If anyone has any input, I would love to hear it.

Already took a serious look at Graphite and concluded it's not right for a few reasons, namely that it tracks numeric time series data, and our information is a bit more complex, and also that it requires you know exactly how much data you will have in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Google graph API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)??

Answer (score 0):

What about an XML / SWF approach?  This website offers some neat graphing tools.  http://www.maani.us/charts/index.php